# How do I connect a backend node js server to a react native app?

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have created an app using react native. I am trying to add notifications to the app using onesignal. I have created a backend server using node.js. When I run my node code from the terminal it works and sends the notification to my iPhone. I would like to be able to link this code to my react native project so that I can get it to run when the app is running rather than always having to call it from the terminal.

is there any way that I can do this?

Here is my node code.

```js
const https = require('https');

const sendNotification = (data) => {
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxx" 
    };

    const options = {
        host: "onesignal.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/api/v1/notifications",
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers
    };

    
    const server = https.request(options, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("Response:");
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
});

server.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('ERROR:');
    console.log(e);
});

    server.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    server.end();
};

const message = {
    app_id: "xxxxxx",
    contents: {"en": "New Notififcation!"},
    included_segments: ["All"]
};
```

Here is my react native code.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
     return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         <HomeStack />
       </View>
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: I think your best option is to add an API-endpoint to your node.js backend app, to which you can make a request from your React app.

Comment: can I ask how I would do that? I'm new to this

Comment: Alright! Welcome to the world of NodeJS :D To create an API, you can use a NodeJS library like Express to handle routing. Within a route you can trigger your desired functions. Express has a very good tutorial to get you started: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

You might also want to think about user authorization and things like that.

Comment: perfect, I do know a little about this. I will have a look into it. Thanks for your help.